# Are there additional agility weapons in the game?

Tags: chronos

I have found three weapons in the game so far and they have all been strength based weapons. I have been reluctant to upgrade my sword as I've been expecting to find a better weapon soon. I'm I just waiting for nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have gone quite far into the game and I finally found another agility weapon. The weapons seem to be based on the environment in which you find it. Since the earliest part of the game has enemies based on strength, any weapons you find there will reflect that.

So if you mostly play agility, you don't actually have to be stuck with your sword throughout the entire game.

Answer (score 1):

You get the scythe and krellite sword later on in the game.

Answer (score 1):

There are three additional agility weapons in the game, but they are not found until after the first few strength weapons, in this order:

- Pan spear
- Krell sword
- Labyrinth scythe

The Pan spear is about 1/3rd the way into the game (once you get to the Pan area). The other two are found in the 2/3rds the way through the game.